# Why it is not printing 2d array value when access directly

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion, comma-operator

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int i,j;
int ans[5][5];
ans[0][0] = 10;
printf(" why this %d \n\n",ans[0,0] );
}
```

and output is some garbage value
i tried this in codeblocks

Comment: You use `ans[0][0]` in one place and `ans[0,0]` in another. The first is right, the second is not.

Comment: Note that `0,0` is the comma operator which evaluates both expressions and uses the value of the last one. That means `ans[0,0]` is the same as `ans[0]`. With a good compiler and warnings enabled you should get a warning about the data type that does not match the format. see https://onlinegdb.com/XuZMqHFIK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared a two-dimensional array

```
int ans[5][5];
```

The element type of the array is `int[5]`. So for example the expression `ans[0]` gives such an array. Arrays used in expressions (with rare exceptions) are converted to pointers to their first elements. So the expression `ans[0]` having the type `int[5]` is implicitly converted to pointer of the type `int *` to the element `ans[0][0]`

In this expression

```
ans[0,0]
```

in the square brackets there is used an expression with the comma operator `0,0`.  As the first operand of the expression with the comma operator does not have a side effect then the above expression is equivalent to `ans[0]`.

That means that in this call

```
printf(" why this %d \n\n",ans[0,0] );
```

that is equivalent to

```
printf(" why this %d \n\n",ans[0] );
```

you are trying to output a pointer using the conversion specifier `%d` designed to output objects of the type `int` that results in undefined behavior.

It seems you mean

```
printf(" why this %d \n\n",ans[0][0] );
```

or

```
printf(" why this %d \n\n", **ans );
```

or

```
printf(" why this %d \n\n", *ans[0] );
```

or

```
printf(" why this %d \n\n",  ( *ans )[0] );
```

As for the comma operator then just consider the following code snippet

```
int i = 0;
ans[0][0] = ( ++i, ++i, ++i, ++i, ++i, ++i, ++i, ++i, ++i, ++i );
```

the result of which is equivalent to the following code snippet

```
int i = 10;
ans[0][0] = i;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are approaching to the array wrong
try this:

```
int main(){
    int i,j;
    int ans[5][5];
    ans[0][0] = 10;
    printf(" why this %d \n\n",ans[0][0] );
    return 0;
}
```

you need to use "[number][number]" to get numbers from 2d array and not [number,number]